# Random variable with zero variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, random-variable

If any random variable has zero variance, then is it right to say that:

> A random variable with zero variance is not a random variable

Comment: According to kolmogorov's definition a random variable can have 1 outcome $\Omega=\{o\}$, then $\sigma$-algebra is the set of subsets of $\Omega$ and the measure of $\{o\}$ is 1. So a random variable with zero variance is a random variable (any map that maps the above o to a single real number is an example)

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that there's nothing *random* (in the usual senses of this word) about a "random variable". Non-zero variation is not a requirement for a random variable.

Comment: Suppose $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y=X$ if $X \in \mathbb{Q}$ but $Y=\frac12$ otherwise.  Then $Y$ is a random variable with mean $\frac12$ and variance $0$ but can take values which are not $\frac12$.

Comment: Ignoring the math, it doesn't even make sense. "x with property y" is still something of type x

Comment: @Henry That’s a mind-warping example, but since that random variable is equal to the degenerate variable almost everywhere, can it *really* take values other than $1/2?$

Comment: @Dave $X$ can take any real value between $0$ and $1$ (it must take one of them and they are each equally likely), and there are an infinite number of rationals in that interval leading to $Y \not = \frac12$, so $Y$ *really* can take other values albeit with probability $0$.

Comment: @Henry Weird! I guess just because two random variables have the same distribution, they aren’t necessarily equal, e.g., $X\sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y=-X$.

Answer (score 19):

$E[(X-E[X])^2] =0 \implies X = E[X]$

Thus $X$ is *almost surely* constant. A better description for such *random variables* is that it follows a [degenerate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution).

Comment: I am slightly confused: $X=E[X]$ is constant, not "almost surely constant", isn't it?

Comment: 'almost surely' is a technical term meaning that any deviation from the stated assertion has zero probability. An example would be, let's say you have an indicator variable indicating whether a number is an integer or not, and then you take the expectation of this over the real numbers from 0 to 10. Of course there are 9 or so locations where this indicator is 1, but the probability of choosing one of these locations is infinitely unlikely (not a technical term, more hand-waving), so the expectation of this indicator will be 0. The indicator takes values that are _almost surely_ equal to 0.

Comment: I think @HughPerkins 's comment should be the answer to the question: an example of a random variable which is actually random (not deterministic) and still has zero variance.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have an indicator variable indicating whether a number is an integer or not, and then you take the expectation of this over the real numbers from 0 to 10. Of course there are 9 or so locations where this indicator is 1, but the probability of choosing one of these locations is infinitely unlikely (not a technical term, more hand-waving), so the expectation of this indicator will be 0, and the variance is 0.

Answer (score 5):

A random variable can have a variance zero, it doesn't become deterministic just because the variance is zero. Mathematicians use the words such as *almost surely* to describe such situations.

Here's an example of such random variable that has variance zero. Let's define the r.v. X as X=0 when $\xi=0$ and X=1 when $\xi\ne0$ where $\xi\sim\mathscr N(0,1)$. This is a random variable because although the probability that a Gaussian variable will take value 0 is zero, the Gaussian variable may take a value 0 nevertheless.

The mean $\mu_x=Pr(X=1)=1$ and the variance $\sigma_X=Pr(X=0)\times 1=0$, because $Pr[X=0]=Pr[\xi= 0]=0$ and $Pr[X=1]=Pr[\xi\ne 0]=1$.